# A transfer function relating jet engine thrust to pitch angle during a phugoid motion

Tags: integration, control-theory, linear-control

<sub>[Crossposted](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/101830) on Aviation SE</sub>

---

I am doing a school project that requires me to find a transfer function that relates the thrust of a jet engine (which could change with time in one way or another) and the aircraft's pitch angle during a [phugoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phugoid) motion. Phugoid motion is when an aircraft pitches and flies up along this pitch angle while maintaining constant thrust. The drag and the weight would slow the aircraft down, causing the pitch angle to decrease as lift--which depends on aircraft velocity along the flight path. Due to the lift being no longer able to counter the weight, the aircraft droops down, accelerated by gravity and its own thrust while speeding up. This increases lift and allows it to climb back up again. Then the cycle is repeated because all of the flight controls are down. My project's goal is to use fuzzy logic to increase and decrease the thrust so the pitch angle and rate of pitch angle change would be damped to 0.

A set of equations describing the phugoid motion: [https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~scott/Book331/Seeing_flight_path.html](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Escott/Book331/Seeing_flight_path.html)

The $\theta$ is the pitch angle:
[https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~scott/Book331/Phugoid_model.html](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Escott/Book331/Phugoid_model.html)

The way I see it, the acceleration/deceleration of the aircraft along the flight path can be found through:
$$a_{fp}(t)=T(t)-D(t)-mg\sin(\theta(t))$$
m is the mass of the aircraft,g is the gravity, T is thrust, and D is drag.

The velocity along the flight path can be found through
$$v_{fp}=v_{fp_0}-\int_{t_0}^{t_1}a_{fp}(t)dt$$
$v_{fp_0}$ is the initial aircraft speed along flight path (a given value).
The thrust is a time-varied input, the drag can be found through
$$D(t)=C_d\frac{\rho(v_{fp}(t))^2}{2}S_{wet}$$
Everything except vfp is known.
The lift of the aircraft is just like the drag:
$$L(t)=C_L\frac{\rho(v_{fp}(t))^2}{2}S_{wet}$$
The lift and drag equation here are all with respect to the inertia reference frame instead of with respect to the flight path.
The pitch angle should be
$$\theta(t)=\theta_0-\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\frac{\frac{L(t)-W}{m}}{\int_{t_0}^{t_1}v_{fp}(t)dt}dt$$
Where $\frac{L(t)-W}{m}$ is the vertical acceleration of the aircraft, $\int_{t_0}^{t_1}v_{fp}(t)dt$ is the displacement of the aircraft from $t_0$ to $t_1$ So this $\frac{\frac{L(t)-W}{m}}{\int_{t_0}^{t_1}v_{fp}(t)dt}$ is actually an angular acceleration. So we integrate this angular acceleration and find the change in pitch angle from initial $t_0$ to "final" $t_1$.

But I can't figure out what to do next, given that there are so many integrals.

Comment: I don't think it will be practical to solve this without resorting to numerical methods. Basically, what you want is a computer program (written either by your or by someone else--there are such programs out there) in which you can specify your lift and drag coefficients, $m$, $S_{wet}$, and the transfer function that determines the thrust. Then the program will predict how the pitch and speed of your aircraft evolve over time.

Comment: @DavidK so there is no transfer function that could do this? I technically just need a way to relate thrust with pitch angle and pitch rate in Simulink

Comment: Simulink is an example of the kind of computer software I was talking about. But you should be using it to solve the trajectory of all the variables at once, not try to integrate any particular variable over $t$. Everything you've written as a function of $t$ can indeed be described as a function of $t$, but none of that is going to help you solve the problem. You discover all the functions of $t$ only when you have finished the solution.

Comment: @DavidK I know. I do not want to integrate or anything. I just want a transfer function that relates thrust with pitch angle and pitch rate, it just that all of these parameters could change with time

Comment: So you define thrust as a function of pitch angle, pitch rate, and maybe speed. Don't worry too much about what these things are as a function of time. Use the software to experiment with different transfer functions to see which ideas work.

Comment: @DavidK so for example, the vfp can just be vfp = v0 - afp*t?

Comment: I don't know what you think that equation would mean or how you intend to use it. The equations I think you should be using have no variable $t$ anywhere in them, except in the form of differentiation with respect to $t$, either $\frac{d}{dt}$ or $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$. I think now you should take a step back and try to understand how your Simulink simulation should work if there is no control input from the aircraft at all--neither control surfaces nor thrust changes. You should have a set of differential equations, none of which contains any explicit function of time, that produce a phugoid.

Comment: You haven't said what course you're doing this for in what kind of school, so this also makes it hard to give appropriate guidance.

Comment: @DavidK I study aerospace engineering, but the course is an ai course. The topic of project I chose is fuzzy logic control

Comment: So from the aero engineering perspective, you should know how to set up the differential equations in Simulink with all control surfaces in fixed position and constant thrust so that when Simulink solves the equations it generates a phugoid. Do that first and make sure it works. Then you can change thrust from a constant to a function of some of the instantaneous values in the differential equation. That's when the AI comes in.